# NullPointerException when trying to do an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I try to do an intent like this :

```
public class CenterAnalyse extends Activity {
    public final static String AGE = "com.mat.archery.statistics.AGE";

    protected MySurfaceView mActivity; 

    public TextView Text;

       public void receiveMyMessage()
       {
           Log.d("Essai", "Test 1");
           Intent intent = new Intent(CenterAnalyse.this, TargetActivity.class);
           Log.d("Essai", "Test 2");
           intent.putExtra(AGE, 1);

           Log.d("Essai", "Test 3");

            // Puis on lance l'intent !
            startActivity(intent);
       }


    }
```

I call `test()` in this code :

```
public class TargetActivity extends Activity {



    protected MySurfaceView mActivity; 


      public TextView Text;

       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_target);

           Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


           Intent i = getIntent();


           int age = i.getIntExtra(CenterAnalyse.AGE, 0);


           if(age == 1)
           {
             test();
             age = 0;
           }
         }



       private void test()
        {
           Log.d("Essai", "Test 5");


            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   if (Text != null) Text.setText("Done");
                }
            });
        }


    }
```

But when `receiveMyMessage()` is call in an other thread, i get these errors :

```
01-08 09:04:41.920: D/Essai(12895): Test 1
01-08 09:04:41.935: W/dalvikvm(12895): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001f888)
01-08 09:04:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(12895): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9
01-08 09:04:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(12895): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-08 09:04:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:120)
01-08 09:04:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
01-08 09:04:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:2900)
01-08 09:04:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at com.mat.archery.statistics.CenterAnalyse.receiveMyMessage(CenterAnalyse.java:26)
01-08 09:04:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at com.mat.archery.statistics.MySurfaceView.onDraw(MySurfaceView.java:137)
01-08 09:04:42.021: E/AndroidRuntime(12895):    at com.mat.archery.statistics.MySurfaceThread.run(MySurfaceThread.java:43)
```

I know i do something wrong, i'm only a beginner in java/android so someone can tell me what i do wrong in the intent, or somewhere else ?

Edit : This is where `receiveMyMessage()` is call :

```
public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

 private MySurfaceThread thread;
 private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
 private Paint paintJaune = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
 int cx, cy, offx, offy;
 private float initX, initY, radius;
 public double distx, disty, distance = 100;
 private boolean drawing = true;
 private boolean first = true;
 public boolean touch = false;

 public TextView Text;

 protected MySurfaceThread msurfacethread; 

public CenterAnalyse mActivity = null;


 public MySurfaceView(Context context) {
  super(context);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  init();
 }

 public MySurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  init();
 }

 public MySurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
  super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  init();
 }

private void init(){
        Log.d("Essai", "TargetActivity  5");


        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        thread = new MySurfaceThread(getHolder(), this);

        setFocusable(true); // make sure we get key events

        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Fleche1Default));
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        paintJaune.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Jaune));
        paintJaune.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        mActivity = new CenterAnalyse();

        Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);



   }

 @Override
 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  drawing = true;
 }

 @Override
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  thread.setRunning(true);
  thread.start();

 }

 @Override
 public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  boolean retry = true;
  thread.setRunning(false);
  while (retry) {
   try {
    thread.join();
    retry = false;
   }
   catch (InterruptedException e) {
   }
  }
 }

 @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onDraw(canvas);
     int width = this.getWidth(); 
     int height = this.getHeight(); 




        if(drawing){
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
            canvas.drawCircle(width/2, height/2, 80, paintJaune);
            canvas.drawCircle(initX, initY, radius, paint);

            if (touch == true){
                distx = (width/2)-initX;
                distx *= distx;

                disty = (height/2)-initY;
                disty *= disty;

                distance = distx + disty;
                distance = Math.sqrt(distance);

                //Log.d("Essai", String.valueOf(distance));

                if((distance + radius/2) < 110)
                {   
                    mActivity.receiveMyMessage();
                }
            }





        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return super.onTouchEvent(event);

        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            initX = event.getX();
            initY = event.getY();
            radius = 30;
            drawing = true;
            first = false;
            touch = true;
        }
        else if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            initX = event.getX();
            initY = event.getY();
            radius = 30;
            drawing = true;
            first = false;
            touch = true;
        }
        else if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            drawing = false;
            first = false;
            touch = false;
        }

        return true;

    }
}
```

And this is where the draw is call :

```
public class MySurfaceThread extends Thread {
 private SurfaceHolder myThreadSurfaceHolder;
 private MySurfaceView myThreadSurfaceView;
 private boolean myThreadRun = false;

public double distance;
public String result;
public boolean touch = false; 


 public MySurfaceView mSurfaceView = null;

 public MySurfaceThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MySurfaceView surfaceView) {
  myThreadSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
  myThreadSurfaceView = surfaceView;
 }

 public void setRunning(boolean b) {
  myThreadRun = b;
 }



 @Override
 public void run() {


  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  while(myThreadRun){
   Canvas c = null;

   try{

    c = myThreadSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
    synchronized (myThreadSurfaceHolder){
     myThreadSurfaceView.onDraw(c);

    }

   }
   finally{
    // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
    // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
    // inconsistent state
    if (c != null) {
     myThreadSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

If someone have a solution tu change the textview from a test on the Draw i take it!!

Comment: _why have you made such an easy task so complex.?_

Comment: Because i didn't find a solution to call a runOnUiThread in a permanent Draw so i try any ideas

Comment: True ... you complicated that too much. One thing comes to my mind is that you shouldn't invoke startActivity() method from non UI thread. But it seems it fails on new Intent(). Try posting this whole block on UI thread.

Comment: CenterAnalyse.java:26, which line is that?

Comment: too much is missing here. i don't understand why call runOnUiThread when you already are on the ui thread (oncreate being called on it and all). I'd guess you are calling startActivity from an unitilialized context, possibly an activity you instanciated yourself (don't, btw)

Comment: May be you should share more of your code where you are calling the receiveMyMessage() method

Comment: I edit the post, the line 26 is : `Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);`
As it's say in some answers now this line is : `Intent intent = new Intent(CenterAnalyse.this, TargetActivity.class);` but there is no changes in the errors

Answer (score 2):

Use this to retrieve intent's data:

```
 Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
 if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey(AGE)) {
     int age = bundle.getInt(AGE);
 }
```

Comment: There is no change, the error come when i try to create the intent not when i try to retrieve the data

Comment: Well, the exception trace's telling that the exception is at your line no. 26 of CenterAnalyse Activity.. Try to debug it and check that whether the intent has been initialized or not.. Well, this is strange.. I have also started new activitied from non-ui threads.. so that's not the problem i guess..

Answer (score 0):

Just use,

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(CenterAnalyse.this, TargetActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("AGE", 1);
```

and in the second class use,

```
      Intent i = getIntent();
       int age = i.getIntExtra("AGE", 0);
```

Doesnt it works.

**Edit-** Have you initialised and created your activity.?

Comment: No, there is no bugs but the text view didn't change so the intent is not link. The bug appear when i try to link the intent

Comment: @MathieuRobert : You should use **CenterAnalyse.this**, instead of **this**. Look at my edited answer.

Comment: @MathieuRobert : By seeing your edit, you are calling this function from a SurfaceView class. I doubt if you can use Actvity's Context here.

Comment: So what can i do to call `runOnUiThread` in a SurfaceView class ?

Answer (score 0):

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);`

Maybe change to

`Intent intent = new Intent(CenterAnalyse.this, TargetActivity.class);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to initialize the `protected MySurfaceView mActivity;` in your application.
Just initialize your `MySurfaceView` activity as :

> ```
>   protected MySurfaceView mActivity;
>     @Override
>        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
>        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
>       ......................
>       mActivity=new MySurfaceView();
>    }
> ```

Comment: possinle, except we don't see any use for this variable

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to you have not mentioned your `TargetActivity` class in menifest file.
please do check it

and use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CenterAnalyse.this, TargetActivity.class);
```

so that it will get proper context of activity

BY seeing your problem I can only say that you have to call `intent` on `UI thread` or have to the original `context` of `activity` as because you are calling `intent` on `thread` and supplying instance of that `thread` not the `context` of `activity`

Comment: unlikely, as this is not what the exception says

Comment: I disagree with you comment as because this may be possible and also code is incomplete

Comment: the exception says nullpointerexception in a context, which indicates the context is used before being initialized. if targetactivity was not in the manifest, the exception would be activitynotfound.

Answer (score 0):

```
mActivity = new CenterAnalyse();
```

cannot be used as a context to start an activity, because it is not properly initialized by the system. You cannot instanciante an activity yourself, it need to be done by android so the context is attached to the application.

You need to use `getContext().startActivity()` from your SurfaceView to start an activity.

Comment: I think a problem come from here but i don't understand how to use `getContext().startActivity()`, when i use only this i've this error : `The method startActivity(Intent) in the type Context is not applicable for the arguments ()` maybe i must put something in () but i don't know what.

Comment: how about, like, the intent ? the one you used already ? when you actually tried to start the activity ?

Comment: I try to call the activity only when i do the intent